# Upload image from React Native to Apollo Server not working?

Tags: node.js, react-native, graphql, apollo-server, image-upload

I have created my backend with `Nodejs` and `Apollo Server`. I am trying to upload an image from my `React Native` client. Here is my backend code

```
Mutation: {
    async singleUpload(_, { fileInput: { file, fileName } }) {
      try {
        const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = await file;
        const stream = createReadStream();
        const path = `./upload/${filename}`;

        const tempFile = { id: 123, filename, mimetype, path };
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const writeStream = createWriteStream(path);

          // When the upload is fully written, resolve the promise.
          writeStream.on("finish", resolve);

          // If there's an error writing the file, remove the partially written file
          // and reject the promise.
          writeStream.on("error", (error) => {
            unlink(path, () => {
              reject(error);
            });
          });

          // In node <= 13, errors are not automatically propagated between piped
          // streams. If there is an error receiving the upload, destroy the write
          // stream with the corresponding error.
          stream.on("error", (error) => writeStream.destroy(error));

          // Pipe the upload into the write stream.
          stream.pipe(writeStream);
        });
        ...then upload it to Firebase Storage
```

When I use `Altair` plugin for `Firefox` browser to upload image , it works fine.

Now for my `React Native` client, I am using `apollo-upload-client` lib. After a user picks image using the Image Picker plugin for React Native , I am creating a file

```
 const file = new ReactNativeFile({
            uri: image.uri,
            type: image.type,
            name: 'Hi there',
          });
```

`ReactNativeFile` is from `apollo-upload-client` lib. Now when I upload it I get an error saying  from my backend saying `TypeError: createReadStream is not a function` which I understand as there is no `createReadStream` parameter in my `ReactNativeFile`

so I decided to change my backend code to something like this

```
const { name, type } = await file;
        console.log("Mime" + type);
        const stream = fs.createReadStream(name);
```

`fs` module is from `nodejs`
Now when I try uploading image from Altair or from React Native , I get an error saying

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
```

Due to my lack of knowledge of backend I am not sure what is causing the issue.
I think if I try uploading it from `ReactJS` instead of `React Native`, my code might work for the backend.
But the image picker for browser and native mobile are very much different and I have not tried doing with `ReactJS` for now

I am following this article  `https://moonhighway.com/how-the-upload-scalar-works` for my backend code

Comment: if backend/API works with altair/graphiql/postman then leave it alone (don't change backend) - adjust your client code to make the same [shape] requests - check raw network requests... or search for RN graphql upload tutorial

Comment: yeah if I start using raw request then I will have to import axios. Tried searching for tutorials , couldn't find any good ones. The Apollo Client for iOS and Android mentions to upload file just like we do it for rest api which is kind of disappointing @xadm

Comment: https://medium.com/@JamesCPoole/uploading-files-with-graphql-apollo-and-react-native-82016ca47d0a